# Access a function in derived class through virtual call to it in base class

Tags: c++, virtual, handle, protected, friend-class

The question comes up with me when reading chapter 13 of *accelerated c++*.

There are three classes involved in this question, e.g. class `Core`, class `Grade` and class `Student_Info`. `Core` is the base class. `Grade` is the derived class inherited from `Core`. `Student_info` is the handle class.

In order to define copy constructor for `Student_info`, we need a virtual `clone` function in class `Core` and we also need to redefine it in class `Grade`. Both functions are under the `protected` label. To access the protected `clone` function of `Core`, the handle class `Student_Info` must be nominated a friend class of `Core`.

However, its says that we don’t need to nominate `Student_Info` as a friend of `Grade` to access its clone function because we can access it only through virtual calls to `Core::clone`. I’m really confused about this. I don’t know how can `Student_Info` access `Grade`’s `clone` function. If cp (of type `Core*`) points to an object of class `Grade`, why can `s.cp->clone()` work? Can some give me detailed elaboration of this?

Relevant parts of code:

```
class Core {     
    friend class Student_info; 
protected:     
    virtual Core* clone() const { return new Core(*this); } 
 };

class Grad {
protected:
    Grad* clone() const { return new Grad(*this); }     
};

Student_info& Student_info::operator=(const Student_info& s) {
    if (&s != this){         
        delete cp;// cp is of type Core*
            if (s.cp)             
                cp = s.cp->clone();
            else             
                cp = 0;     
    }     
    return *this; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Student_info` is a friend to `Core`, so it is able to access `Core::clone()`. This is why `s.cp->clone()` works. Where the call is dynamically dispatched is internal and irrelevant.

To which method the call is dynamically dispatched cannot be known a priori (statically). The compiler does not know it, let alone checking its access modifier.

Comment: But when cp points to an object of class Grade, cp->clone will call Grade::clone(). But Student_Info is not permitted to do this since it’s not a friend of Grade. What’s wrong with this logic?

Comment: To which method the call is dynamically dispatched cannot be known a priori (statically). The compiler does not know it, let alone checking its access modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Private protected and public protect ways of naming things, not the things themselves.

You are naming the base class clone; you only need permission to access it by that name.  The fact it is actually something else is not relevant.